# Git rebase onto with mutliple revision sets

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase, rebase

We are using `git rebase --onto` to pick commits from a branch to another branch. Let's say from for simplicity the develop branch to the release branch.

```
1----A----B----C----D----2----3----E----F---G----H----4----5----6 develop
```

Out of the above I need to merge all of the "character" revisions from develop into release, it is important to note that I need to ignore the numeric revisions.

So what we do is run the rebase onto for each grouping. For example in the above there are 2 groupings, A to D and E to G.

```
git rebase --onto release 1 D #rebase the first range of revisions from the develop branch and base it on the release branch

git rebase --onto release 3 H #rebase the second range of revisions from the develop branch and base it on the release branch.
```

The problem is that for each grouping we need to run this command which is not convenient.

Is there any way that I could run `git rebase --onto` once and specify all the required revisions then in one single command

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this, what you've got here is just the most inconvenient.  Easiest might be interactive rebase and delete the ones you don't want.

Comment: Indeed, just `git rebase -i --onto release 1` followed by selecting the patches you want will work, if you don't mind doing it in EDITOR rather than at a shell.

Comment: Rebase is the wrong tool for picking good ("cherry") commits from one branch into another.  The `git cherry-pick` command does precisely that: you identify the cherries to pick, and it picks (copies) them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way that I could run git rebase --onto once and specify all the required revisions then in one single command

I would suggest to use `git cherry-pick` instead.
Use the `cherry-pick` with a `commit range` and you can pass as many ranges as you wish

```
# set the range of commits you are interested in 
# A should be older than B.
cherry-pick A..D E...H
```

And it will merge the given ranges into your current branch